# Listview not showing up using custom adapter-android

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Can someone tell me why the Listview is not showing up? I call the items from a CustomAdapter and its string from object class. It will show multiple return from web in a listview. Here's my code including the custom adapater.

```
public class ClaimVoucherDetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{

ArrayList<VoucherObj> items;
Button claimVoucher;
EditText etEmail,etVoucherCode;
TextView tvName,tvEmail,tvVoucherCode,tvIssueBranch,tvDateIssued,tvExpiration,tvStatus,tvVoucherSource;
String sName,sEmail,sVoucher,sIssueBranch,sDateIssued,sExpiration,sStatus,sVoucherName,sCustomerID,sType,empID,branch,brID;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
DisplayImageOptions options;
ImageView voucher;
Spinner spinEmployee;
SQLiteAdapter mysqlAdapter;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
VoucherObj vouch;

 private ClaimVoucherAdapter m_adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.voucher_details);
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    ImageLoaderConfig();

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .build();

    mysqlAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(ClaimVoucherDetailsActivity.this);
    mysqlAdapter.openToRead();

    branch = mysqlAdapter.getValue("SELECT branch from branch_tb");
    brID =  mysqlAdapter.getValue("SELECT ID from branch_tb where branch = '"+branch+"'");
    TextView branchTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.branch);
    branchTV.setText(branch);



    Intent intent = this.getIntent();       
    sCustomerID = intent.getStringExtra("customerID").trim();
    sType = intent.getStringExtra("type").trim();
    sName = intent.getStringExtra("name").trim();
    sEmail = intent.getStringExtra("email").trim();
    sVoucher = intent.getStringExtra("voucher").trim();
    sIssueBranch = intent.getStringExtra("branch").trim();
    sDateIssued = intent.getStringExtra("issued").trim();
    sExpiration = intent.getStringExtra("expiration").trim();
    sStatus = intent.getStringExtra("status").trim();
    sVoucherName = intent.getStringExtra("vouchername").trim();
    String employ = intent.getStringExtra("employeeid").trim();

    ListView lstitems = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);       
    items = new ArrayList<VoucherObj>();        
    vouch = new VoucherObj();
    items.add(vouch);                         
    m_adapter = new ClaimVoucherAdapter(ClaimVoucherDetailsActivity.this,R.layout.list, items);
    lstitems.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

Voucher Class

```
public class VoucherObj {

public String customerID="";
public String type="";
public String name="";
public String email="";
public String voucher="";
public String branch="";
public String issued = "";
public String expiration="";
public String status = "";
public String vouchername = "";
public String employeeid = "";

}
```

Adapter Class

```
 public class ClaimVoucherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

 private ArrayList<VoucherObj> items;
 private LayoutInflater vi;

 TextView tvName,tvEmail,tvVoucherCode,tvIssueBranch,tvDateIssued,tvExpiration,tvStatus,tvVoucherSource;
 public ClaimVoucherAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,  ArrayList<VoucherObj> myList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    this.items = myList;
    vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    final VoucherObj i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) {

        final VoucherObj ei = (VoucherObj)i;
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.voucher_details, null);

        tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvEmail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
        tvVoucherCode = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvVoucherCode);
        tvIssueBranch = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvIssuingBranch);
        tvDateIssued = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvDateIssued);
        tvExpiration = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvExpirationDate);
        tvStatus = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);     
        tvVoucherSource = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvVoucherSource);


        tvName.setText(items.get(position).toString());
        tvEmail.setText(items.get(position).toString());
        tvVoucherCode.setText(items.get(position).toString());
        tvIssueBranch.setText(items.get(position).toString());
        tvDateIssued.setText(items.get(position).toString());
        tvExpiration.setText(items.get(position).toString());
        tvStatus.setText(items.get(position).toString());
        tvVoucherSource.setText(items.get(position).toString());





}
    return v;}}
```

Comment: you need pass your list too to super constructor

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan how can I do that?

Comment: Try printing the length of your listview to make sure that all- the items are added in the list. You can do so by printing array_list_object.size()

Comment: How can I put it in my code? Please help? :(

Comment: I've a doubt. is that your VoucherObj Model class is  complete or not?

Comment: Try printing that after items.add(vouch), so that it will be printed everytime you add a content

Comment: It is complete. I think the problem is in my Custom Adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need pass your list to super constructor too,

use following code:

use

```
super(context, textViewResourceId, myList);
```

when you use `ArrayAdapter` you must pass your list to super constructor for handling size of your list.  you can use `BaseAdapter` too and override `getCount()` method for returning size of your list

**EDIT**

you have `super(context, textViewResourceId);` on your code, first line of your constructor, remove that and put my code.

so you must have:

```
public ClaimVoucherAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,  ArrayList<VoucherObj> myList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, myList);
    this.items = myList;
    vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 }
```

you need change `ArrayAdapter<String>` to `ArrayAdapter<VoucherObj>`

**Update**

as you say on comment you got **NPE** on `tvName.setText(items.get(position).toString());`

so 2 possibility is exists:

1- `tvName` is null, for handling that check `tvName` is exist on `voucher_details`.

2- `items` is null,

**Update 1**

you use `items.get(position).toString()` and i think you have one empty object to your list.

so you have 2 way,

1- override `toString` method on `VoucherObj` class.

2 - change `items.get(position).toString()` to one other value

Comment: where should I put that?

Comment: in your Adpter's Constructor.

Comment: but its already there in the Custom Adapter.  public ClaimVoucherAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,  ArrayList<VoucherObj> myList)

Comment: I get error it says The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, int, ArrayList<VoucherObj>) is undefined

Comment: Thanks. but I have new error on the getView it says null pointer exception. Starting from this line tvName.setText(items.get(position).toString());

Comment: @jajaja this one I'm expecting. You don't have a data in VoucherObj object. So the items arraylist is null. Create setter and getter for each element in VoucherObj class and set values.

Comment: I put strings in VoucherObj. And iput it here ListView lstitems = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);       
    items = new ArrayList<VoucherObj>();        
    vouch = new VoucherObj();
    items.add(vouch);                         
    m_adapter = new ClaimVoucherAdapter(ClaimVoucherDetailsActivity.this,R.layout.list, items);
    lstitems.setAdapter(m_adapter);

Comment: did you check id of `tvName`?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan yes. but i think the problem is I call the ID from other XML Activity. Thats what I want to do to put that xml inside the listview. So if its multiple return, its gonna be okay coz its in Listview.

Comment: did `tvName` in the `voucher_details`? please post logcat and layout file

Comment: I posted the whole main class. Check it out. The listview is showing up now but the values of tvName shows the location of the VoucherObj?? How that happen?

Comment: please post `toString` method of `VoucherObj` or constructor of that

Comment: I put the toString method in the adpater class

Comment: Or how where should I put the VoucherObj toString method?

Comment: see my Update 1 @jajaja

Comment: I have no toString method in VouchrObj class. Its all strings. Thats where I get strings

Comment: What do you mean by one other value?

Comment: if you want get your String value you need write get and set method for your class, then use something like `getType()`

Comment: as your property is public you can access those with `items.get(position).customerID` or other type, but you need write set and get method for your property of class

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan can I see an example?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638964/set-and-get-methods-in-java please

Answer (score 1):

Change this from

```
 public ClaimVoucherAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,  ArrayList<VoucherObj> myList) {
 super(context, textViewResourceId);
 this.items = myList;
 vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 }
```

to

```
 public ClaimVoucherAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,  ArrayList<VoucherObj> myList) {
 super(context, textViewResourceId,myList);
 this.items = myList;
 vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 }
```