# Java how do I use a set Method?

Tags: java, methods

For example I have this:

```
public int getAge(){
     return age
}
```

and now I have to use a `setAge()` but I don't know how.

Comment: No, it's not too primitive. Being a *duplicate* could be reason for closing, but otherwise it's a perfectly valid and reasonable question. Just because it's simple for someone else doesn't mean it's simple for this user.

Comment: Yes..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638964/set-and-get-methods-in-java