# Box type OR create new type

Tags: java, variables, point

Looking to use one variable to define an `x1, x2, x3, x4` for a method. Is there a type that exists that would allow me to do this? I could just do 2 `Point`s, but I'd rather just have one variable. If one doesn't exist, am I able to create a type similar to this that I can make useable in all classes in my package?

Thanks!

Comment: Write a custom class with the fields you require.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja , I'm still learning java, how abouts would I do this? Sorry if its a noobish question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered defining your own [tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)?

```
public class PointsTuple
{
     public Point Point1;
     public Point Point2;

     // replace with appropriate setters and getters if you want.
}
```

Hopefully you will give your class a more descriptive name than `PointsTuple` but you get the idea. Here I used public fields but if you are familiar with [encapsulation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm) you may opt to use [set & get methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6638982/2015959).

---

Comment: Could you show me an example of a getter and setter for one Point? With that I should be able to figure the rest out

Comment: @Nathan Ok bud. Done.

Comment: Wait is that all I need??

Comment: @Nathan I think so. You tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! The rectangle!

`java.awt.rectangle`

`Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)`

Example:
`Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x1, y1, x1-x2, y1-y2)`

Comment: Ah if Rectangle was defined as (x1, y1, x2, y2) I would go for it, it looks like a custom class better suits me this time though. +1 anyways!

Comment: Just note: The above solution (if you decide to use it) requires x1 >= x2 and y1>=y2. Else, you will be sending negative width and height. If you do not know which one is bigger, you can add Math.min/max before.

Comment: @Nathan Tried that, however, Math.abs will not work in the case that x1 >= x2 and y1>=y2 is indeed true! `int x1 = 200, y1 = 200, x2 = 100, y2 = 100;` and using abs results in the rect 200,200,300,300.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a custom class like this:

```
class MyPoint{

    private int x1;
    private int x2;
    private int x3;
    private int x4;

    //Setters and Getters for the points
}
```