# Sort array of objects by object properties

Tags: java

How to sort array of objects(i.e array of objects of class student) by marks attribute but without using comparator?

```
    class Student
{
    private int rollNo;
    private double marks;
    public Student(int rollNo, String name, double marks) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
        this.marks = marks;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) In Java always prefer lists to arrays unless you have a very good reason not to; 2) Why without using comparator?

Comment: Implement a sort algorithm.

Comment: Looks like Homework

Comment: Without a comparator, just write your own sorting algorithm (quicksort, bubblesort, your pick) that goes over the array of said objects and directly compares the attributes and put the objects in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the standard Java `sort` implementation, then modify `Student` so that it implements `Comparable<Student>` .... appropriately.  Then search the Javadocs to find the method for sorting a list.  (Hint: look for "sort" in the javadoc index ...)

If you can't do that, then you may need to implement a sort algorithm from scratch.

That should be enough to get you started on your homework :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should create `get()` and `set()` methods for the `Student` class.

Then, you can loop through your array of Student objects and use `get()` to compare.

[Set and Get Methods in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638964/set-and-get-methods-in-java)